# How to fetch Reddit post from a scraped csv

Tags: python, csv, reddit

I have a csv file with Reddit ID. In first column there may be 2-6 ids but in second column there is always 2 IDs. I have to write a script so that i can fetch the posts from IDs for the both column.

[image: pic1]

Your help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

So first of all you need to read that file.

```
import csv
with open('yourfilename.csv', mode ='r') as file:
csvFile = csv.reader(file)
```

Taken from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reading-csv-files-in-python/)

Next you would want to split each column to a list, so that you can scrape multiple ids

```
idList = []
for line in csvFile: # loop each line
  for columns in line: # loop each column
    for element in columns.split(' '): # loop each element
      idList.append(element)

print(idList)
```

Taken from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-split/)

Comment: From your solution i will get a list, But i need to keep the csv file as it is. So the rows and columns needs to be intact, as i will do further processing on the csv file.